# There are 2 AndroidManifest.xml files in my Android Eclipse Developer app, which one should I edit?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I am using the Android Eclipse Developer app, and with each new Android Project, there are two `AndroidManifest.xml` files.

The first is located at
`projectName/bin/AndroidManifest.xml`

The second is located at
`projectName/AndroidManifest.xml`

Should I make the same changes to both `AndroidManifest` files?

Or should I only make changes to the `projectName/AndroidManifest.xml` (second choice)?

Answer (score 4):

`projectName/AndroidManifest.xml`; you only need to modify this file.

The `projectName/bin/AndroidManifest.xml` file is automatically generated, so you don't need to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

Do a **Project > Clean** in Eclipse and one should disappear.

Comment: I just did the Project Clean (twice), but both AndroidManifest.xml files are still there

Answer (score 1):

Just leave aside the AndroidManifest that located in your bin folder.

Simply only edit your AndroidManifest that located outside which is your second choice. projectName/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Always use AndroidManifest.xml file which is located in root folder.

"projectName/AndroidManifest.xml"